# Android Broadcast doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have such problem - "my Broadcast" doesn't receive any information. What I'm doing wrong?

**Code example**
My activity with Broadcast registration:

**Main Activity**

```
        DriverCheckBroadcast broadcast = new DriverCheckBroadcast(this);
    IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter("MY_BROADCAST_CHECK");
    // регистрируем (включаем) BroadcastReceiver
    registerReceiver(broadcast, intFilt);

    startService(new Intent(this, DriverCheckService.class));
```

**Methode that put parcels to Broadcast**

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Example> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            Example result = response.body();
            LatLng driverlatlang = new LatLng(result.getGpsLatitude(),result.getGpsLongitude());

            intent.putExtra("address",customizeText(result.getAddress()));
            intent.putExtra("latlng",driverlatlang);
            intent.putExtra("model",result.getModel().getName());
            intent.putExtra("brand",result.getModel().getIdBrand());
            status = result.getStatusName();
            service.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
```

**Methode that get parcels in Broadcast**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    activity.driverlatlang = intent.getParcelableExtra("latlang");
    activity.model.setText((CharSequence) intent.getParcelableExtra("model"));
    activity.brand.setText((CharSequence) intent.getParcelableExtra("brand"));
    activity.address.setText((CharSequence) intent.getParcelableExtra("address"));
}
```

Comment: how do you create an `Intent` you use in `sendBroadcast` ?

Comment: you are using wrong pair of Bundle.put/Bundle.get ... asked bazillion times ... if you put String with putExtra then you should use getStringExtra

Comment: check my answer.. I am doing this way.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34740462/3713967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set action when sending broadcast.

**Try this** :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("MY_BROADCAST_CHECK");
```

Because your receiver aspects type : `MY_BROADCAST_CHECK` but when you sending broadcast you did not give any, that's why your receiver does not get any information.

Answer (score 0):

create intent  and send Broadcast this way

```
Intent i = new Intent("a");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(USER_ID, user_id);
i.putExtras(bundle);
mContext.sendBroadcast(i);
```

declaration of intent filter

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("a");
filter.addAction("b");
filter.addAction("c");
```

receive broadcast

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    try {
                        if(intent.getAction().equals("a"))
                        goToPage(new a());
                        if(intent.getAction().equals("b"))
                        {
                          // you can call other event and function here
                            Fragment fragment = new b();
                            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            goToPage(fragment);
                        }
                        if(intent.getAction().equals("c"))
                        {
                           // you can call other event and function here
                            Fragment fragment = new c();
                            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            goToPage(fragment);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, filter);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should receive data from `intent` using `Bundle` like this :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
 if (extras != null) {

   Object value1=extras.get("latlang");
   Object value2=extras.get("model");
   Object value3=extras.get("brand");
   Object value4=extras.get("address");
 }

}
```

and then `settext` value's accordingly.